# Can't install nVidia driver on notebook running Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, acer-aspire, nvidia-graphics-card

Today, I reinstalled Windows 10 on my Acer Aspire 5755G. One of the first things I wanted to do was installing a driver for my built-in GeForce GT 630M. I tried:

- The Windows 10 driver (nvidia.de)
- Choosing the specific card and installing this driver
- Installing GeForce Experience
- The driver you can download on the Acer website
- Device Manager -> Action -> Add Legacy device -> choosing the folder where the installer unpacked the drivers
- resetting the BIOS settings and trying all above (+reflashing it)
- going into safe mode and trying all above

My BIOS is on the latest version, I reflashed it before installing Windows 10. In the BIOS menu, there is an option for which card is used. Sadly you can only decide between "integrated" and "switchable"... I can not install the driver when this setting is set to "integrated".

Every time, the setup fails ("The Graphics Driver Could Not Find Compatible Graphics Hardware" or similar).

Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to http://laptop.bg/system/pdfs/343/original/as5755G_spec_v1-1-1.pdf this is not a GT 630M, but a GT 540M

Comment: I do not have bluetooth so... Also there is a sticker which says 630M